# ring automorphism $\mathbb Q[x]\rightarrow \mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

we need to find all ring automorphism from $\mathbb Q[x]\rightarrow \mathbb Q[x]$, I know every field automorphism $\mathbb{R}$ is identity and i can prove it, same will be for $\mathbb{Q}$, could any one tell me what will be in this case? thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Any endomorphism $f:\Bbb Q[x]\to\Bbb Q[x]$ is uniquely determined by $f(x)$.

*Update:* Say, $f(x)=p$ where $p\in\Bbb Q[x]$. Then, for example, what $f(x^2+2x+1)$ *has to be*?

Think over that $f$ must be identity on $\Bbb Q$. And, until neither surjectivity or injectivity is required, $f(x)$ can be *anything* in $\Bbb Q[x]$. To ensure injectivity, $f(x)$ must not be a constant, and to ensure surjectivity -- that linear polynomials arise as images under $f$ -- $f(x)$ must have degree $1$. Besides that, it seems, anything is good.

Comment: be more illustrative please.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $\phi\colon \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be an automorphism. Give a bound on the degree of $g(x)=\phi(x)$? Give a bound on degree of $h(x)=\phi^{-1}(x)$. What is the degree of $g(h(x))$?

Answer (score 1):

Say $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[x] $ is an automorphism.Any automorphism is uniquely determined by its image of the generators. Hence if $\phi(x)=p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x], $ then for any $q(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, we have  $\phi(q(x))=q(p(x))$.
$\phi$ is an automorphism implies that $\phi$ is injective and surjective, which further implies that $\phi(x)=p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $>0$ and $<2$ respectively. Thus we conclude that $\phi(x)=p(x)=ax+b$ where $a \neq 0$

To conclude, note that for any $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$
$$\phi(p)+\phi(q)=p(ax+b)+q(ax+b)=(p+q)(ax+b)=\phi(p+q)$$
and

for any $m(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x],$ we have
$$\phi\big(m\Big(\frac{x-b}{a}\Big)\Big)=m$$

in other words $$\phi^{-1}(m)=m\Big(\frac{x-b}{a}\Big)$$

P.S- Surjectivity implies $\operatorname{degree}(p)<2$ follows because $q(p(x)) \neq x$ , if $\operatorname{degree}(p)>1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: Q[x]\to Q[x]$ be an automorphism.

$f(1)= f(1^2)= f(1)^2\implies f(1)=1\implies f(n)=n$.

$f(1)= f(m.1/m)=mf(1/m)\implies f(1/m)=1/m$.

So $f(m/n)= m f(1/n)= m/n$ for all $m/n\in Q$. That is, $f$ is an identity on $Q$. Therefore, if $f(x)$ is known, then the $f$ is known.

Let $f(x)=b_0+b_1 x+\cdots+b_k x^k= b_0+ xh(x) $, where $h(x)=b_1 +\cdots+b_k x^{k-1}$. $f$ is onto so there are $p(x), q(x)$ such that $f(p(x))= h(x), f(q(x))=x$.

$f(x)=f(b_0+p(x)q(x))\implies x=b_0+p(x)q(x)$

So deg $p(x)=0$, deg $q(x)=1$ as deg $q(x)$ can't be $0$.

Let $p(x)=p_0$. Hence $f(x)= b_0+xp_0$. If $p_0=0$, then $x=b_0$ hence $p_0\ne 0$.

Hence, for any $g(x)\in Q[x]$, we have $f(g(x))= g(f(x))= g(b_0+xp_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:  What do you know about what a ring automorphism does when you restrict it to the constants $\mathbb Q$? To be an automorphism, what must it do to $x$?

Comment: on $\mathbb{Q}$ it is identity and $f(x)=x\mapsto f(x)=x$ to be an automorphism.

Comment: Why must $f(x)=x$? $f(x)$ is a polynomial. What must its degree be? Will any polynomial of that degree work? Justify your answers to these. What happens if you replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by a different field such as ${\mathbb Q}[i]$?

Comment: I am not sure please, teach me.

Comment: What must $f(1)$ be? $f(n)$ for $n$ a natural number and then for $n\le0$? What about $f(n/m)$ for $m\ne0$, $m$, $n$ integers? As I read your question, you can do it for $\mathbb R$ but the arguement there is much more difficult than for $\mathbb Q$.